# SQL - get only row with min delta time between columns Items

Tags: sql

Here I have the  `Table1`  which has two Columns time ;  `Time1`  and  `Time2` . 
The  `Time1`  is the same for a given  `Item` , while  `Time2`  depends on  the  `Code` .
For every item what I need is only the row whose delta Abs( `Time2` - `Time1` ) in the lowest.

[image]

Which are the following rows:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's your RDMBS?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please never post data as image but always as text

Answer (score 0):

Use a Rank() window function on DeltaTime, then filter for rank=1 in an outer query.

```
Select * From (
    Select Item, Time1, Code, Time2, DeltaTime,
        Rank() Over (Partition By Item Order By DeltaTime) as TimeRank
    From Table1
    )
Where TimeRank=1
```

This will report both records if there is a tie for lowest.  If you want only one record in case of a tie then substitute a row_number() function for the rank() function.

**Alternatively,**

You can use a correlated subquery like this:

```
Select * From Table1 X
Where DeltaTime= (Select min(DeltaTime) From Table1 Y
                  Where X.Item=Y.Item)
```

This is slightly more compact and easier to read but many DBMS implementations can't execute them efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and the first picture is the table you have, you could just do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Item HAVING min(DeltaTime);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that picture isn't the table he has.